# Insert space before the cursor, then move cursor before the newly added space in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a simpler way to perform a common editing pattern I use in Vim.

Given the following code...

[image]

I want to add a new condition to the if clause *before* the existing condition, like so:

[image]

The way I currently do this is...

1. Starting in Normal mode, I move the block cursor to the first letter "r" after the left parenthesis:

   [image]
2. I then press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter Insert mode which places the Insert cursor between the left parenthesis and the letter "r".
3. I then press the Space Bar which inserts a blank space between the left parenthesis and the letter "r":

   [image]
4. And then I press the <kbd>←</kbd> key once to move the cursor before the newly added space.
5. I then type merrily away adding in the new condition `site == "HQ" &&`

---

### The Problem

Whenever I have to add text at a location where there is not already white space on either side, I have to go through this editing pattern. Why? Because I find it easier to have a blank space separating the new text I'm adding from the existing text to the right.

For example, if I start adding the new "if" condition right after step 2 above (without the blank space to separate), then as I type, it looks like this:

[image]

Having the words smushed together like this as I type is disconcerting, and it usually throws me off. If I add the blank space initially (as in the steps above), then I rarely get confused at what I'm looking at as I type in the new information:

[image]

But it's almost equally annoying to me to have to move my right hand away from "home position" in order to reach for the <kbd>←</kbd> key in step 4 above; or, similarly, to exit out of Insert mode and re-enter Insert mode to begin typing again with the cursor to the left of the newly added space.

---

### Summary

**I want to start typing with the benefit of having one blank space to the right of the Insert cursor in locations where there was previously no white space on either side of the cursor.**

**Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with fewer (or simpler) keystrokes or by using an existing Vim command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of accomplishing what you want is to create a key mapping which goes into insert mode and adds a space automatically:

```
nnoremap {key} i<space><esc>i
```

You can use whatever you want for `{key}`, since I don't know what would be most optimal for your vim configuration.  Another mapping you could use would be this:

```
inoremap {key} <space><left>
```

Preferably, `{key}` would be a `Ctrl-` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have multiple options:

1. Do it the vim way: `i <esc>i`. Mapping esc to something easy-to-press like caps lock makes it pretty painless
2. Map something like alt-h to ← in Vim or system-wide. That saves one keystroke compared to the above
3. Do a custom mapping like `nnoremap <c-n> i <esc>i` or `inoremap <c-b> <space><left>`